# Cannot import QWebPage from PyQt5 in Python 3.5

Tags: java, python, web-scraping

I am now trying to write some codes for scraping web content from some Java rendered page. I found some example from the web by using PyQt5. However, when I get my Python 3.5 installed with PyQt5.5.7 but failed importing its module (ImportError: cannot import name 'QWebPage'). I attached the code below for reference. Very much appreciated if anyone can suggest as to what to do to solve this problem, or any other ways to scrap Java rendered webpage content.

```
# standard imports
import sys

# third-party imports
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebPage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication



class Render(QWebPage):
    """Render HTML with PyQt5 WebKit."""

    def __init__(self, html):
        self.html = None
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
        self.mainFrame().setHtml(html)
        self.app.exec_()

    def _loadFinished(self, result):
        self.html = self.mainFrame().toHtml()
        self.app.quit()


url = 'https://impythonist.wordpress.com/2015/01/06/ultimate-guide-for-scraping-javascript-rendered-web-pages/'

# get the raw HTML
source_html = requests.get(url).text

# return the JavaScript rendered HTML
with Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600)):
    rendered_html = Render(source_html).html

# get the BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(rendered_html, 'html.parser')

print('title is %r' % soup.select_one('title').text)
```

Answer (score 5):

QWebPage was a class in the module QtWebKit in PyQt4. This module has been depreciated and seperated as an optional add-on to PyQt5. To install:

```
pip install PyQtWebEngine
```

QtWebKit has been replaced with QtWebEngineWidgets and the corresponding class that has replaced QWebPage is QWebEnginePage. So you should say:

```
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using this
    from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebView,QWebPage